# How to listen to and decode an RTMP video stream with Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtmp, pyav

How can I listen to and decode an RTMP video stream with Python? Such as with the ffmpeg command

`ffmpeg -listen 1 -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app`
I tried this:

```
import av
container = av.open('rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app',listen=True)
for frame in container.decode(video=0):
    frame = frame.to_ndarray(format='bgr24')
    ...do some thing with the frame...
```

But I got an error:

> open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'listen'

Comment: Please add a `pyav` tag. Users are downvoting and trying to close your question, because they don't realize it's a programming question (with PyAV subject). In my opinion it's a helpful question because the subject is undocumented. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyAV correct syntax is:

```
container = av.open('rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app', options={'listen': '1'})
```

`av.open` accepts an `options` dictionary argument.
In the code, `'listen'` is the key and `'1'` is the value.
This is the equivalent to `-listen 1` argument of FFmpeg CLI.